# Ruby - Heroku migrating to Cedar 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to migrate to heroku cedar 14 - following these instructions:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration

I can't push the migration - I keep getting this error:

```
Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this error last week when trying to upgrade a Heroku app to Cedar-14 following their instructions. The problem was that the app was using an older version of Ruby that Cedar-14 didn't support. I had to first upgrade the version of Ruby I was using (to 2.1.7, in my case) and then I was able to upgrade Cedar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Heroku upgrade failed trying to download the updated Heroku buildpack. It seems to be an issue at Heroku.

I suggest you to contact them.